# How can I find duplicate records \ values after left join?

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

I have:

- TABLE1 with ID, and Name.
- TABLE2 with ID, and Address.

I want to get ALL TABLE1 records and add a STATUS column:

- If this record exists in TABLE2 - 'OK'.
- If this record is not exist in TABLE2, then research a match by last 2 digits, else 'NO_RECORD'.
- If this record has duplicate records in TABLE2, then if the duplicate records has the same Address choose one record  - 'OK', and if they doesn't has the same Address - 'DUPLICATE'.

Meanwhile, I've started with this:

```
SELECT t1.id,
 t1.name,
 t2.Address,
 iif(Address is null, 'No_RECORD', 'Ok') as 'status'
FROM Table1 as t1
left join Table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

For example:

Table1

```
 id     Name
 111    aaa
 222    bbb
 333    ccc 
 444    ddd
 555    eee
 666    fff
 777    ggg
 888    hhh
 999    iii
```

Table2:

```
id  Address
111 rr
922 hfh 
444 vbv
444 vbv
555 xxa
555 plo
555 plo
666 wqq
777 gyt
999 ree
999 ree
```

My accepted results are:

```
id  name Address 'status'
111 aaa  rr      Ok
222 bbb  hfh     Ok
333 ccc          No_RECORD
444 ddd  vbv     Ok
555 eee          Duplicate
666 fff  fff     Ok
777 ggg  wqq     Ok
888 hhh          No_RECORD
999 iii  ree     Ok
```

- `444` is not duplicate because the 2 table2's records address are match,
- `555` is duplicate because the 3 table2's records address are mismatch,
- `999` is not duplicate because the 2 table2's records address are match.
- `222` is ok because tha 2 last digits of it's id are exist in tabl2: "922".

How can I continue? (I use sql query in access).

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, no images. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: What is this supposed to mean?  "If this record is not exist in TABLE2, then research a match by last 5 digits, else 'NO_RECORD'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what "match by last five digits" is supposed to mean.  It has nothing to do with your sample data, so I'm just ignoring that part of the question.

What you want to do is to aggregate on `table2` before doing the `join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.name,
       iif(multiple_addresses = 0, address, null) as address,
       switch(t2.id is null, "No_Record",
              multiple_addresses = 1, "Duplicate",
              1=1, "OK"
             ) as status
from table1 as t1 left join
     (select id, min(address) as address
             iif(min(address) = max(address), min(address), 0, 1) as multiple_addresses
      from table2
      group by id
     ) as t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement to get this status:

```sql
SELECT
 t1.id,
 t1.name,
 t2.Address as add2,
 case 
  when t2.Address is null and exists (select 1 from Table2 temp where temp.id = t1.id) then 'DUPLICATE'
  when t2.Address is null then 'NO_RECORD'
  else 'OK' end
 as 'status'
FROM Table1 as t1
left join Table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.Address
order by t1.id
```

As you can see I added `and t1.name = t2.Address` to the join clause to make sure you have non null Table2 values only when you want so.

About the `case when`, the first condition checks if 1) no corresponding record was found 2) there are records for the same id, meaning 'DUPLICATE'. The second condition checks that there are no corresponding record, and we already know there are no duplicates (as it would have fallen into the first case).

[Working SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90493b/2).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer works almost perfect. I've edited my question, can you read it again?

Comment: What does not match what you expect exactly ?

Comment: Would be easier if we add sample, pre join data in addition to expected result by the way

Comment: I will not update my answer unless you add sample data that cover all the cases you mentionned, especially the last two digit one.

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks!